# Python returns unexpected answer

Tags: python

This is my program (a very simple one):

```
__author__="soham"
__date__ ="$Aug 12, 2012 4:28:51 PM$"

from math import sqrt

class Point:
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

    def get_dist(self, other):
        return sqrt(abs((self.x - other.x)^2 + (self.y - other.y)^2))

    def is_rect(self,other,another,yet_another):
        return (self.get_dist(other) == another.get_dist(yet_another)) and \
               (self.get_dist(another) == other.get_dist(yet_another)) and \
               (self.get_dist(yet_another) == other.get_dist(another))


a, b, c, d = Point(4,3),Point(4,9), Point(7,3), Point(7,9)

if a.is_rect(b,c,d):
    print "Rectangle."
else:
    print "No, not a rectangle!"
```

This returns no. [A similar program written in Java](http://www.sohamchowdhury.com/2012/08/how-to-find-out-whether-four-points-make-a-rectangle-java/) returns the expected answer.

I'm *very new* to Python. Help!

Comment: >>> a, b, c, d = (4, 3), (4, 9), (7, 3), (7, 9)
>>> points = sorted([a, b, c, d])
>>> points
[(4, 3), (4, 9), (7, 3), (7, 9)]
>>> zipped_points = zip(*points)
>>> zipped_points
[(4, 4, 7, 7), (3, 9, 3, 9)]
>>> x_points, y_points = zipped_points

Comment: From a design standpoint, it looks odd for a `Point` object to have a  method called `is_rect`, since you generally aren't testing if a `Point` is a rectangle. Better would be to have a static method that takes 4 points: `Point.is_rect(a,b,c,d)`. Also, argument names that indicate which corner each point represents would help with the readability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exponentiation in Python is `**`, not `^`.

`^` in Python is actually the [*bitwise xor* operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

For exponentation, you can also do `pow(x,y)` instead of `x**y`.